# What's the aperture/sensor size for the mid-2011 27" iMac FaceTime HD camera?

Tags: mac, camera, facetime

I'm working on a project where I need to convert from pixels to mm and need to find the aperture or sensor size on the FaceTime HD Camera.  Specifically, I have the mid-2011 27" iMac.  I can't seem to find any detailed technical specifications on the newer FaceTime camera.  Anyone privy to these details?

Comment: If you use the camera to take a picture of a ruler, you can then measure the distance between the glass covering the camera and the ruler to make a start on your project. However, unless you are controlling for the 3D position and alignment of whatever you are measuring, you might find distortion and off-axis positioning have measurable effects on the image rendering even assuming you have a parallel placement of whatever you are measuring (both vertically and horizontally).

Comment: I'm using OpenCV for the project.  Specifically, I'm looking to find the apertureWidth and apertureHeight parameters for the [calibrationMatrixValues](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#calibrationmatrixvalues).  Rereading the documentation, it looks as though these parameters are poorly named as they're actually looking for the physical width and height of the sensor.

Comment: Makes sense - we will be a good place for people to help document what hardware is used, but if you want to ask that exact code level question on our coding site, [Stack Overflow would be a good place to ask if other developers have found good values you might be able to reuse rather than engineer a solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

***tl;dr - As a starting off point, eyeballing it I'd estimate around ƒ/2.2 - ƒ/2.8 aperture.***

This isn't an exact answer, I put the iPhone 7+ front camera (which has a ƒ/2.2 aperture and a 'focal length in 35mm' of 32mm) next to the 720p FaceTime HD camera on a macbook. Eyeballing it, the image on the mac seems to be the same or maybe ~5% smaller in FOV. So I estimate around ƒ/2.2 - ƒ/2.8 , maybe ƒ/2.4 in aperture.

Answer (score -1):

On the iMac's features [page](http://www.apple.com/imac/features/) it is stated that:

> The built-in **720p** FaceTime HD camera lets you make video calls that are so clear, it seems like everyone’s in the same room.

This means that the FaceTime HD Camera can offer you a **1280x720** resolution as a **hardware maximum**, but, it's the software you'll be using it with, which will *decide* the resolution.

Comment: That's not an appropriate answer. Unfortunately its hard to find the Specs. Its important o know the Aperture size / Sensor / Pixel Size / Focal Length / ISO etc. for specific studio interview requirements.